# Can I use zesty/artful/bionic packages in xenial ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, espeak

I have xenial Ubuntu and wanted to install espeak by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak-ng-espeak
```

But I got this error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package espeak-ng-espeak
```

Then I went to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and searched for it and found it inside these three distos: `zesty/artful/bionic`

How can I install it?

Answer (score 5):

If you can meet the dependencies, you can install it; however, as Dobey says:new packages usually have newer dependencies. Thus, trying to install can easily become a dependency nightmare. Also, mixing version, like mixing distros, could cause hard to trace problems. It is best to see if it has been backported.

To enable backports add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Or try to find a PPA providing it for other version releases.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, no, you can't just take packages from a newer version of Ubuntu and install/run them on older versions. They often have newer dependencies as well, and depending on what those are, they make break other parts of the system. Therefore, the general rule is that packages need to be [backported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) to work on older releases.